# PDO statement updates 0 values instead of null or empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a PDO update statement but it is entering 0's on empty values.

- I want a empty value to enter null
- I want a zero value to enter zero

Here is my code:

```
include 'dbconfig.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

try {
    $options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    
    $setStr = "";

    $values = array();

    foreach($data as $field => $value) {
        $setStr .= "$field=:$field,";
        $values[$field] = $value;
    }

    $setStr = rtrim($setStr, ",");


    $values['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE products SET $setStr WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->execute($values);


    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($count > 0) {
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success','message'=>'Product ID # '.$id." successfully updated."));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'=>'Product not successfully updated'));
    }

}catch(PDOException $e){
    
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'=>$e->getMessage()));
}
    $conn = null;
```

What is the best way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the columns in your DB are set to allow NULL values?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439)

Comment: Welcome to the community Jack.  Because `$data` is being posted by the user, they keys of the array *cannot be trusted* and so your `$setStr .= "$field=:$field,";` line is at risk of [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

Comment: Don't expose PDO error messages to the user. Please remove that try-catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for an empty string in your loop, and convert it to `null`.

```
    foreach($data as $field => $value) {
        $setStr .= "$field=:$field,";
        $values[$field] = $value === "" ? null : $value;
    }
```

Comment: That's definitely one way to do it, there's not any setting built into PDO to do this?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's not normal to treat empty strings as `NULL`.

Comment: `NULL` is usually used for missing data, not data that's explicitly set to an empty string.

Comment: So you want 0 to turn into an empty string, and an empty string to turn into `NULL`?

Comment: `if ($value === "0") { $value = ""; } elseif ($value === "") { $value = null; }`

Comment: No I am just wondering how to turn empty to empty and zero to zero and null to null then

Comment: Right now it makes empty 0

Comment: How would I set empty as empty instead of 0?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? If it's a numeric type, you can't put an empty string in there.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah, it's a decimal.

Comment: If you want `0` to become `NULL`, you can do `$values[$field] = $value === "" || $value === "0" ? null : $value;`

Answer (score 0):

PDOStatement::[execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) considers every parameter to be a string.  In some databases the driver deals with this without issue, but if you want to specifically type values you need instead to use [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).  With this typing, we can type null (or empty) values to the database-null type (instead of whatever the column default is) - see my `bindEmptyAsNull` function.

Also, since I'm using a *trusted* source for the column names, I can safely use your `$setStr` pattern for building the update params, but note you might not want to update a column that isn't included in the `$dangerData` associative array (as it is, if it isn't submitted, the column will be cleared).

```
<?php

//... your setup code, including $pdo

// List all the names of the columns in the products table here - you havent' provided enough info so I'm guessing
$keys=["name","cost","weight_grams"];
$dangerId = $_POST['id'];
$dangerData = $_POST['data'];

/**
 * Convert null values into PARAM_NULL types, not
 * @param $type Should be one of the [PDO::PARAM_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) constants
 */
function bindEmptyAsNull($stmt,$name,$value,$type=PDO::PARAM_STR) {
    //If you want empty string to be considered null too:
    //if ($value===null || $value==="") {
    if ($value===null) {
        //Note the column needs to support null types
        $stmt->Value($name,null,PDO::PARAM_NULL);
    } else {
        $stmt->bindValue($name,$value,$type);
    }
}

//Build the set string
$setStr='';
foreach($keys as $col) {
    $setStr.=$col.'=:'.$col.',';
}
$setStr=substr($set,0,-1);//Remove the trailing comma

//Create the statement
$stmt=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE products SET $setStr WHERE id=:id");

//Bind the danger values
// NOTE: The only way you could automate this (re-read the keys array) is to also have an
// associative array of key:type mapping too
$stmt->bindValue(":id",$dangerId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
bindEmptyAsNull($stmt,":name",$dangerData["name"]);
bindEmptyAsNull($stmt,":cost",$dangerData["cost"]);
bindEmptyAsNull($stmt,":weight_grams",$dangerData["weight_grams"],PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
// .. Further processing
```

Comment: PDOStatement::execute considers every parameter to be a string. do you have any evidence to support this claim in regard of null values?

Comment: when you bind a variable using PDO::PARAM_STR, a null value is sent to database as null. so again, do you have any reason for this bindEmptyAsNull of yours?

Comment: The PDO documentation is ambiguous on the topic.  While there was an attempt to move `PARAM_NULL` from PHP in 7.0, it did not happen - meanwhile there are several PDO *drivers* that still require `PARAM_NULL` (including SQLAnywhere and IBM/DB2).  On a driver by driver basis NULL maybe acceptable as a string (certainly the language distinguishes between empty string and null - unlike Oracle) and inserted as a NULL in the database (vs coerced), but if you want this to work for any PDO driver you'd need to prove this works everywhere.  Have you evidence proving otherwise?